# cannot get previous page name on device using ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I update my ionic version.

Ionic version 3.4.0

If user not authenticated my root page is Login Page. after user logged in and go to dashboard Page.user When click on hardware back button go to Login Page.

I Need if user authenticated click on hardware back button does not go to Login page.Display msg "Do you want to exit?"

Because  I need get previous page name.

I used this Code

```
this.navCtrl.last();
```

It's work fine on browser.But not work on device.

I run my app.

I consoled the value

```
t {_isHidden: false, willEnter: e, didEnter: e, willLeave: e, didLeave: e…}
```

and its return the page name is 't'.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can pass the name of the current page while you route to a new page. Then you can use that name from new page.

Example (Assume we are routing from page A to page B)

in page A

```
this.navCtrl.push(B,{previousPage:'A'});
```

in page B

```
class B{
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     let previousPage= navParams.get('previousPage');
  }
}
```

**====UPDATE=======**

I cant understand why you want previous page name for achieve this. any way your requirement can achieve as following.

1. in your app component set root page as `loginPage`.

   `public rootPage: any = LoginPage;`
2. Then, If user login success. route to dashboard page by calling

   `navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage); // here user will route to the home page and set it as root`
3. You can re change the root page as login page when user click sign out

   `navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);`

then if user is authenticated root page will be `HomePage` and if user click back button user will leave the app.

Hope this will help you :) enjoy Ionic ;)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.How can i do this app.component.ts

Comment: what is your root page. ? describe your requirement please (It is better if you can give `app.component.ts` and `rootPage.ts` conetent)

Comment: I also use this.nav1.setRoot(pagename).But still does not fix this issue.i tried to this way console.log(this.nav.getActive());
 console.log(this.navCtrl.getActive().component.name); This just returns the letter t on the device but does work in the browser.

Comment: I wish to handle the hardware back button for that i need to get the name of the current view.